# Creating a complex home page outside of Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I have been tasked to create a very specific, complex home page for our Joomla site.  My first attempt was to install a module that let me include php code, CSS styling and other not-allowed stuff in the Custom HTML Module (it's called Flexi Custom Code).  And it works well - as designed.

But I'm running it problems with the basic fact that all modules will be imbedded in several layers of Joomla's div structure down to the section I install that custom module (like mainbody-top for example).

So I get ugly white space at the bottom and margins on the sides I do not want. Plus lots of other things I am finding that I need to override or zero out.

My basic question is this: Is there a way to create a custom home page that Joomla does not control, but all the links on the home page go into Joomla and everything else is controlled by Joomla?

Would I have to replace the index.php in the root dir? Or the template dir?  Or is there another way that is the commonly accepted method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish it in different ways.

1) You can create a new template and assign it to home menu item.

2) In the current template, open index.php file and check if you are on the homepage. If yes, then do what you need, just add it where you want your output to appear

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
        echo 'Homepage';
}
```

Comment: I think 2) is a great idea!  I'm going to give it a try and come back here in a couple hours. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I'm going to take this answer because it would have worked if not for a couple of unforeseen issues I ran into:   

First, I want to intercept the page after the menu and logged-in user info is figured out and displayed, so this forced me to intercept the code mid way down.

Second, the template I am using is infested with div tags to the point that I couldn't figure out how many endDiv tags to include after your short little code.  I am using JSN Epic Pro, and (while a good template) uses a TON of DIVs.

Comment: The way I actually ended up doing it was in the front page module I am using (Flexi Custom Code), I create a <style> block and overrode all the template CSS that was messing up my display.  For example, I put display:none; for the template areas like mainbody and footer that I wanted to 86 on the front page.  I also had to include a few margin-bottom: -15px; etc to override some of the spacing the JSN Epic had specified up above in the auto-gen code.

It's not perfect, and I may attempt your solution at a later date, this will get me to my next deadline. :)  Thanks!

Comment: As long as you managed to solve it before the deadline, it's good :)